# $\mbox{Im}(A^*S^{1/2})\subseteq \mbox{Im}(S^{1/2}) \Leftrightarrow \exists \,M>0;\;\|S^{1/2}Ay\| \leq M \|S^{1/2}y\| ,\;\forall y \in E\;?$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $E$ be a complex Hilbert space and
 $\mathcal{L}(E)$ be the algebra of all bounded linear operators on $E$.

> If $S\in \mathcal{L}(E)^+$ and $A\in \mathcal{L}(E)$, why the following equivalence holds
>   $$\mbox{Im}(A^*S^{1/2})\subseteq \mbox{Im}(S^{1/2}) \Leftrightarrow \exists \,M>0;\;\|S^{1/2}Ay\| \leq M \|S^{1/2}y\| ,\;\forall y \in E\;?$$

Thank you everyone !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just an application to following Douglas's theorem

> Let $P,Q\in \mathcal{L}(E)$, then
>   $$\mbox{Im}(P)\subset \mbox{Im}(Q)\Longleftrightarrow \exists M>0\,; PP^*\leq M QQ^*.$$

So,
$$\mbox{Im}(A^*S^{1/2})\subseteq \mbox{Im}(S^{1/2}) \Leftrightarrow \exists M>0;\;A^*SA\leq M S$$
Hence,
$$\mbox{Im}(A^*S)\subseteq \mbox{Im}(S) \Leftrightarrow \exists M>0;\;\|S^{1/2}Ay\| \leq M \|S^{1/2}y\| ,\;\forall y \in E.$$